# How to add multiple git account on a local repository

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

My client gave me the access and control all over our web server. He already set and clone our repository to our server. The problem is, when I wanted to pull the updates from our `git` repository to our server, git is looking for my client's `Bitbucket` account and I don't know the password of my client's account. Is their any way possible to add my own `bitbucket` account for this? I am one of the collaborators on this repository at `Bitbucket` so I am thinking that maybe I could just add and use my own credentials to pull the updates. Is it possible? And how may I do it?

By the way, I am just using `ssh` login to log into our server through the use of `putty`.

Answer (score 0):

If using `ssh://`, you can do some hack. I use this for my github account, I think bitbucket is similar.

First, change ssh_config file in ~/.ssh/config on your server (suppose you are using Linux). add these lines:

```
host user2.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /path/to/user2/id_rsa
```

you should make sure your own **private** key is in `/path/to/user2/id_rsa`. BE CAUTION if this is shared host.

then add another remote url:

```
git remote add user2 git@user2.github.com:user2/repo.git
```

so you can fetch or pull from user2

```
git fetch user2
```

or

```
git pull user2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to add additional remote to your repo.

```
git remote add myserver <login@hostname>
git remote add bitbucket <bitbucketlogin>
```

Then, you should define remote from which you want to pull.
`git pull myserver` (to pull from your server)
same to push
`git push bitbucket` (to push to bitbucket)